# Remote URL Completion in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, svn, bash-completion

I'm currently adding support for remote url completion for svn in Bash. I'm currently using a modified bash-completion-svn that figures out when to trigger the completion on URls looking like

```
  svn+ssh://$HOST/$DIR/prefix_string
```

I have managed to extract the parenting directory part of the URL (`svn+ssh://$HOST/$DIR`) and called `svn ls` in it and

```
  cur_suffix=prefix_string
```

Now what is left is how to use the directory part of the URL and the `prefix_string` the user typed after it (can be empty) to make the completion happen. Can I use `compgen` to make this work?

That is to get list of possible completions if last character in url is a slash or a complete directory if suffix is empty.

Currently I'm using

```
  fix=( $(compgen -o nospace -W "$remote_fileds" -- $cur_suffix))
```

to make completion happen for URLS such as

```
svn://HOST/DIR/a
```

to complete into forexample

```
svn://HIST/DIR/a_file
```

It however always picks the first alternative no matter what and always inserts a space eventhough I have written `-o nospace`. How do I prevent completion compgen from completing if there are other possible matches (prefix `a` is nont unique) and how do I make these matches print below the cursor without moving the cursor. Can only `complete` do this?

Comment: Have you succeeded in your attempt? Can you share some where your work? I'm also very interested in URL completion for subversion.

Answer (score 2):

For my bash completion scripts, which necessarily run on across a variety of versions of bash with differing levels of support for completion, I use the following idiom to attempt the best "complete" possible, then gracefully fallback to at least something that should work; e.g., assuming a command `svn2`, and a completion function called `_complete_svn2`:

```
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _complete_svn2 svn2 2>/dev/null \
 || complete -o default -o nospace -F _complete_svn2 svn2 2>/dev/null \
 || complete -o default -F _complete_svn2 svn2 2>/dev/null \
 || complete -F _complete_svn2 svn2
```

Ideally "`-o nospace`" exists and works, but if it doesn't, you can fallback to "`-o default`".

Also, the above example uses a function to generate the completions, arbitrarily called `_complete_svn2`. Perhaps you can try using something like that also. The following example works for me, showing matching options, not adding in the extra space, etc (it intentionally does not complete "-" options):

```
_complete_svn2() {
    local options="one two three four five"
    local cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    COMPREPLY=()
    [[ ${cur} != -* ]] && COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${options}" -- ${cur}) )
}
```

E.g., (and no space is added after "five")

```
$ svn2 f[tab]
five four
$ svn2 fi[tab]
$ svn2 five
```